# How to load dependencies / uber jar as a single java database object

Tags: java, oracle

Simply put, my issue is the following: I wish to load Java classes as individual compact objects and then publish them, but these classes have dependencies, which causes issues with the DB. Namely, if I tried loading uber/fat jars through this command:

```
CALL dbms_java.loadjava('-r -v -f /home/usr/javastuff/Application.jar');
```

I get +350 Java database (schema) objects, causing issues with the server (sometimes; it's not relevant) and it becomes chaotic to manage so many objects from a single dependency. If I had even more dependencies, the number of Java database objects would skyrocket. To give an example, imagine this Java class (**ojdbc** is just a placeholder):

```java
import java.sql.SQLException;
import oracle.sql.BLOB;

public class Application {
    public static Long BlobLength(BLOB myBlob) throws SQLException {
        // Do Logic
        return myBlob.getLength();
    }
}
```

I wish for this type of method to be loadable and publishable without incurring thousands of Java database objects from its dependencies. In other words, I want these methods to come from self-contained units, for reuse and organizational purposes. Uploading every dependency jar individually is also acceptable, if that is possible through Java resources or alike.

I welcome any solution (ie using oracle packages), if it's a weird work-around. I just want to avoid having thousands of useless Java objects in my DB from dependencies I've only used once.

Comment: @Jorn No, I am not running the application inside my database. The jar is compiled locally and then transferred to the server hosting the database (Location: /home/usr/javastuff). Once the jar is uploaded, I run the load method from the database by using Oracle SQL developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not be an issue. If it creates 350 schema objects then that is what it requires to load the JAR into the database and you just have to accept that.

- If you only use them once then use them and then unload them.
- If you cannot track all the objects then create a separate user (and schema) and load the JAR into that user/schema and grant the `EXECUTE` privileges on the functions that you need to call to the main user/schema and then drop that temporary user afterwards.
- If the issue is that you are using dynamic SQL and reading the objects from the schema's data dictionary and the extra 350 items is causing the performance issues then add filters to exclude the java objects when you query the data dictionary *(Note: this would not be an Oracle problem, it would be a problem with your dynamic SQL code)*.
- If your server does get performance issues from having 350 extra objects in the schema (and it is not related to you querying the data dictionary) then open a ticket with Oracle support (under your support contract) and get them to address the performance issues.